# App Crashes on iOS 16: Troubleshooting Tips for Xcode 15 Users

Tags: flutter, xcode, app-store-connect, release

I am currently using Xcode 15, and I have made a social media management tool. I have released the app in the App Store. Currently, I am an iOS 17 user, and I have heard from some people that this app is not opening for iOS 16 devices. I dont know how to solve this problem. When I am using the iOS 16 emulator, the app is running fine, but people are getting this app crash problem, specifically for iOS 16. Is there any way to rectify the problem or to solve it?

I tried running with an emulator iOS 16 on it, it was working fin but in real devices its crashing